# Wily not upgrading to Xenial

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have a Wily box, that is not upgrading to xenial it doesnt throw errors or complain of dependencies, it just says there is nothing to update.
This is ubuntu Mate.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
$ sudo update-manager -d
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found

$ sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
```

should I change the sources list manually in `/etc/apt/sources.list` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change `release-upgrades` file on `/etc/update-manager` directory, in that file you can use the option to upgrade either to LTS or normal release upgrade:

```
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Change the value of prompt from `lts` to `normal`:

```
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# Default prompting behavior, valid options:
#
#  never  - Never check for a new release.
#  normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
#           release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
#           the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
#           release.
#  lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
#           will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
#           the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
#           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
#           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
#           determine if a newer release is available.
Prompt=normal
```

Save the file, then exit.

Comment: will do. (Im a little confused by this, where 16.04 is an LTS, and 15.10 is the immediate predecessor to it.) I'll give that a go.

Comment: Note that this option should not be  used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS release, whereas your 15.10 is not LTS.

Comment: It's always been safer to upgrade one version at a time. If on LTS, it's okay to skip all in betwen and go directly to the next LTS. If all method fails in your case, manual sources.list editing is the last option. But, do prepare for breakages. All the best.

Comment: It is risky to upgrade to a new version. You had better backup your data before starting. Did you run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' to get wily up to date? Did you remove PPAs and any program packages that are non-standard? If still no luck, you could try keeping the /home directory (and make it a home partition) and make a fresh installation (except keeping 'home'). Select 'Something else' at the partitioning window in the installer and do *not* format the home partition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying this is the preferred solution, only that it is what I did..
I went into /etc/apt/sources.list and converted everything that said Wiley, to xenial. when I ran `sudo apt -get update` again, I got new packages. I upgraded, and now my box has 16.04 on it.